# Использовать ранее выбранное значение во вложенном запросе

Tags: postgresql

Можно ли во вложенный запрос передать уже выбранное значение и использовать его вместе с агрегатной функцией?

```
SELECT  sum(p.Count), 
    sum(p.Price)/sum(p.Count), 
    (select sum(r.Count) k from "Rashod", unnest("Rashod"."Composition") r  where  "Rashod"."NameSklad"='Sklad'  and r.Name = 'Огурчик' )  
FROM "Prixod", unnest("Prixod"."Composition") p  
where  "Prixod"."NameSklad"='Sklad'  and p.Name = 'Огурчик';
```

Возможно сделать что то вроде следующего:

```
   SELECT  sum(p.Count) Sm, 
        sum(p.Price)/Sm, 
        (select sum(r.Count)*Sm from "Rashod", unnest("Rashod"."Composition") r  where  "Rashod"."NameSklad"='Sklad'  and r.Name = 'Огурчик' )  
    FROM "Prixod", unnest("Prixod"."Composition") p  
    where  "Prixod"."NameSklad"='Sklad'  and p.Name = 'Огурчик';
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `select sum(p.Count) * (select sum(r.Count) ...)`

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, мне нужно использовать полученное значение во вложенном запросе, т.е. поместив его куда нибудь, далее доставать

Comment: `select Sm, Pr/Sm, (select sum()*Sm ...) from ( select sum(p.Count) Sm, sum(p.Price) Pr from "Prixod",...) X`